# How can I define a node class, which extends another node class, in the metamodel of Soley Studio?

Tags: class, graph, data-modeling, graph-databases, metamodel

Any Soley Studio users?
I started to define the metamodel for my graph. I want to define two node classes (`ProdFunction` and `ProdPart`), which both extend another node class (`ArchitectureRelated`).

But everytime I check for errors or build the solution it gives me this error:

> "ArchitectureRelated" is a error type but a node type is expected

I tried different names for the class but it did not change. Are there special keywords to define a "node type"?
The code for my node meta model is:

```
node class ProdFunction extends ArchitectureRelated{
mode:string;
name:string;
}

node class ProdPart extends ArchitectureRelated{
name:string;
partnumber:int;
hierLevel:int;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the metamodel you can only extend defined classes. Therefore you have to define `ArchitectureRelated` as a node class. From my understanding you do not want to create instances of this class? So I defined it as an `abstract` class.

Also remember that the highest superclass has to extend `IdentifiableNode`, `IdentifiableDirectedEdge` or `IdentifiableUndirectedEdge`.

I would recommend you to use your superclass `ArchitectureRelated` for the attribute `name:string;` and let it inherit to the classes `ProdFunction` and `ProdPart`.

```
abstract node class ArchitectureRelated extends IdentifiableNode{
name:string;
}

node class ProdFunction extends ArchitectureRelated{
mode:string;
}

node class ProdPart extends ArchitectureRelated{
partnumber:int;
hierLevel:int;
}
```

You can find more about defining a metamodel here: [Soley Help Center (Metamodel)](https://support.soley.io/article-categories/metamodel/)